# Is anyone using Babel/6-to-5 in a production Rails app?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ecmascript-6, babeljs

The benefits of using ES6 for Rails frontend are very attractive.

I've made a topic branch in our Rails app that uses [babel](https://babeljs.io/) to transpile ES6 to ES5 via the asset pipeline. It works well, but as always I am weary of technical debt. Is there anyone that has good/bad reports of using such a system in production?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a growing list of users, some are detailed in this [issue](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/364)

Where possible babel tries to provide the most performant polyfill for ES6 features and this is backed up by their test suite. However, for some of the problems there are often more performant es5 solutions available, at the expense of code clarity, speed of code production etc etc.

In general though, I guess it would be up to your own apps performance testing to dictate whether any lack of performance (if any) is outweighed by speed and ease of development and maintenance.

I've only ever used in it simple to intermediate complexity programs (in Node and in the Browser) and never witnessed any performance problems or had any issues updating babel (I may have been lucky with this though). I've used it for stuff like dashboards, filterable lists, data management stuff, other little bits and pieces such as React components. None of it outrageously complex though.

I guess the other thing that might be of use to you is to note that the project lead is incredibly active, the project is moving at breakneck speed and issue responses on both github and gitter are quick and informative.